# Use argparse to send selective arguments to another python script

Tags: python, argparse

How do I use argparse to send selective arguments to other scripts. The scripts invoked are imported as modules and the folder structure is as below:

```
Directory Structure - hello.py
                    - cloud_module
                          - script1
                          - script2
```

In hello.py script, I am trying to invoke scripts based on argument conditions and pass selective remainder arguments -

hello.py

```
from cloud_module import script1,script2
import argparse


def parse_arguments(parser):
    parser.add_argument('--name', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--cloud', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--service', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--zone', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--billing', type=str, required=True)

def parse_command_line_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parse_arguments(parser)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    arguments = args.__dict__
    return args

def output(args):

    if args.name == 'script1':
     **// Pass values to script1.py: cloud & service**

    elif args.name == 'script2':
     **// Pass values to script2.py: zone & billing**

if __name__ == "__main__":
    arguments = parse_command_line_arguments()
    output(arguments)
```

script1.py

```
import argparse


def parse_arguments(parser):
    parser.add_argument('--cloud', type=str, required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--service', type=str, required=True)

def parse_command_line_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parse_arguments(parser)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    arguments = args.__dict__
    return args

def func1(arguments):
    print('this is script1')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    arguments = parse_command_line_arguments()
    func1(arguments)
```

Comment: If it's an option, I would reconstruct the code to have explicit functions using the arguments. Then you just call the matching function from the main script with the matching arguments - in main: `script1.main(args.cloud, args.service)`

Comment: If not, just use `subprocess`: `subprocess.call(['python', 'script1.py', '--cloud', args.cloud, '--service', args.service])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use subparsers for parsing different scripts with different arguments. Here is a simple example for the same

subparser_example.py

```
import argparse


def script_1_run(a, b):
    print( f'Running script 1 with {a}, {b}')

def script_2_run(x, y):
    print( f'Running script 2 with {x}, {y}')

def add_parser_for_script1( parser: argparse.ArgumentParser ):
    parser.add_argument('-a', '--argument_a', type=str, dest='a')
    parser.add_argument('-b', '--argument_b', type=str, dest='b')

def add_parser_for_script2( parser: argparse.ArgumentParser ):
    parser.add_argument('-x', '--argument_y', type=str, dest='x')
    parser.add_argument('-y', '--argument_x', type=str, dest='y')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    subparser = parser.add_subparsers(title = 'Script select', dest='script_type')
    subparser.required = True
    
    add_parser_for_script1(subparser.add_parser('script1'))
    add_parser_for_script2(subparser.add_parser('script2'))

    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    if args.script_type == 'script1':
        script_1_run(args.a, args.b)
    elif args.script_type == 'script2':
        script_2_run(args.x, args.y)
```

Usage:

for script 1

```
py subparser_example.py script1 -a argument_a -b argument_b
```

for script 2

```
py subparser_example.py script2 -x argument_x -y argument_y
```